# Bundle can't find copied framework from XCode

Tags: xcode, macos, frameworks, bundle

I have an XCode project which copies `SDL.framework` to my app bundle and, up until recently, this worked fine. I could give my bundle to someone who didn't have `SDL.framework` and it would work. But yesterday a friend of mine said my app was crashing because it couldn't find `SDL.framework`. I removed `SDL.framework` from my /Library/Frameworks folder to test it on my machine and he's right. Even though `SDL.framework` exists in my bundle the app still crashes because it can't find it.

Why would this be? The only thing I can think of is that the last time I did a working build was on MacOS 10.6 and using XCode 3. I'm now on 10.7. I've tested a new build with XCode 3 and XCode 4 but both produce the problem listed above.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me the other day when I was building a tool for sending Email.  I was linking against the Pantomime framekwork.  Here are the settings that I had to set in order for it to start working and stop crashing with "could not find library"  You can see where I have the framework in relation to the project files / workspace files.

[image]